# Jump to a specific subViewController in Swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented swiping. It has five subViews. Its working well normally.

Now, under a specific case, I need to go directly to fourth  subViewController. After that swiping should not disturb user should be able to swipe forward and back as working before this jump.
How to handle this?

I have use these lines of code to implement swiping:

```
    let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0" ,bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.myscrolview.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1",bundle: nil)

    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame=frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.myscrolview.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2",bundle: nil)

    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2.view.frame=frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.myscrolview.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3",bundle: nil)

    var frame3 = vc3.view.frame
    frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
    vc3.view.frame=frame3

    self.addChildViewController(vc3)
    self.myscrolview.addSubview(vc3.view)
    vc3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



    let vc4 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController4",bundle: nil)
    var frame4 = vc4.view.frame
    frame4.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 4
    vc4.view.frame=frame4

    self.addChildViewController(vc4)
    self.myscrolview.addSubview(vc4.view)
    vc3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    self.myscrolview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 5, self.view.frame.size.height-66)
```

Comment: "fourth subViewController" is that above or below the current viewController in the stack?
(When I say above, I mean the user is yet to see it)

Comment: It might be above or below. whatever current viewController is, It must switch to fourth one.

Comment: You must provide some code if you need help, too few informations..

Comment: Well if it's that broad, simply present this "fourth view controller" on swipe... Just like you would present any other view controller

Comment: @ByronCoetsee it works good when i swipe orderly. But in a specific case I need to jump to fourth viewController. I tried this :                               let ViewController4:ViewController4 = ViewController4()
self.presentViewController(ViewController4, animated: true, completion: nil)   but after opening fourth viewController, I can't swipe

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano                                                                                let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0" ,bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(vc0)
        self.myscrolview.addSubview(vc0.view)
        vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self) and same for other viewControllers

Comment: Sir, you must update your question with this code according to the stackoverflow question rules. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask